# Repeat array in for loop

Tags: php

I was creating an array and I need to repeat this array base on the number loop. How can I repeat in a for loop.

```
 for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++) {
     $array = array(
       'name'          => 'Name 1',    
       'id'            => '1',
       'items'         => array(
          array('name'  => 'item 1', 'id'  => 'itemid1'),
          array('name'  => 'item 2', 'id'  => 'itemid2'),
     )
  );
 }
```

Comment: So you are asking for dynamic number?

Comment: No. my intention is to loop that 1 array into number of specified number sample 10. It will generate 10 arrays using that one array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append new array instead rewriting:

```
$array = [];

for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++) {
     // Here
     $array[] = [
       'name'          => 'Name 1',    
       'id'            => '1',
       'items'         => [
          ['name'  => 'item 1', 'id'  => 'itemid1'],
          ['name'  => 'item 2', 'id'  => 'itemid2'],
     ],
  ];
}
```